# Update NuGet 1.6 keeps failing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I use VS10 and recently NuGet1.6 came out and I tried to do normal update and it kept failing with the following message,

"Install Error : VSIXInstaller.SignatureMismatchException: The signature on the update version of 'NuGet Package Manager' does not match the signature on the installed version. Therefore, Extension Manager cannot install the update.
   at VSIXInstaller.Common.VerifyMatchingExtensionSignatures(IInstalledExtension installedExtension, IInstallableExtension updateExtension)
   at VSIXInstaller.InstallProgressPage.BeginInstallVSIX(SupportedVSSKU targetAppID)
"

Then I read somewhere someone said just uninstall NuGet and re-install it, well I uninstalled NuGet in the Control Panel of Windows, because the Uninstall button of NuGet in VS10 is grayed out (why is this the case?).  But still could not install NuGet1.6, it run into the same error.  Could someone help please!

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might need to Run Visual Studio 2010 As Administrator in order to get the NuGet 1.6 extension installed.

I agree that it is silly that the upgrade from within VS2010 doesn't work. I have tried this several times across several machines (a home workstation without any restrictions, a work machine with tied down profiles) and it always fails.

Comment: I was able to uninstall it in VS run as Admin, then I re-installed.  Pretty user-unfriendly.  Thanks James!

Answer (score 9):

There is a known issue when upgrading NuGet to 1.6 from an older version when running Visual Studio SP1. From the [NuGet 1.6 Release Notes](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-1.6):

> If you are running VS 2010 SP1, you might run into an installation
>   error when attempting to upgrade NuGet if you have an older version
>   installed.
>
> The workaround is to simply uninstall NuGet and then install it from
>   the VS Extension Gallery. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2581019
>   for more information.
>
> Note: If Visual Studio won't allow you to uninstall the extension (the
>   Uninstall button is disabled), then you likely need to restart Visual
>   Studio using "Run as Administrator."

Answer (score 1):

Run Visual Studio 2010 Administrator, and the UnInstall option is available.

Uninstall --> Restart --> Install new version.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't run Visual Studio as Administrator, so I just uninstalled the extension from VS, downloaded the VSIX file from the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c), then ran the install.